# 2.3x DM Serial Port Connections

Tags: serial-port, dm-script

I'd like to acquire an image, send a command to a serial port, take another image, send a new command, etc (using GMS 2.3x).

It seems like `LaunchExternalProcess()` would be cumbersome to use (you'd have to have a unique command prompt expression for each command to the serial port, right?).

I would assume `SerialControl.dll` would be easier to use, but I don't know where to get it. Would using the commands in `SerialControl.dll` be more efficient than using `LaunchExternalProcess()`? 
The image acquisition times are long so communication speed is not a major factor.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know in which GMS configurations `SerialConrol.dll` is installed with - it is for sure only in online installations - but if you have the DLL, then using the commands therein seems to be the better way to go about the serial port communication. In particular, if you want it to be a two-way communication where the script should also receive something via that connection.
However, if your installation doesn't have the DLL I would strongly advise against copying it from a different installation which has it, as compatibility between versions is not guaranteed and a mismatch can really mess with you.

I have never tried the `LaunchExternalProcess` for serial communication so far. If you give it a test and it is fast enough for you, I don't see any problems there neither. It surely is giving you more flexibility, and I wouldn't be too concerned about it being "cumbersome". In the end, somebody always has to put some code somewhere. Depending on what you need, you can neatly wrap one or two script-methods around the commands, and from there on it is just "a simple call" to be used as well.
Making a two-way communication with 'LaunchExternaProcess' is trickier though and requires one to be a bit creative and storing things intermediately to a file-location.

---

One should note that there currently is no official documentation on the script commands in the SerialControl.DLL and that they are not a Gatan supported feature, which generally means: *You can use them if they work, but you can't complain or request help if they don't or get removed in later versions.*

The commands in SerialControl.dll for the RS232C interfaces are:

```
            Number SPOpen( Number port, Number baud, Number stop, Number parity, Number data )
            Number SPOpen( String prefix )
            void SPClose( Number serialPortL )
            Number SPSendString( Number serialPortL, String string )
            Number SPSendHex( Number serialPortL, String string )
            void SPFlushInput( Number serialPortL )
            Number SPGetPendingBytes( Number serialPortL )
            Number SPGetTime(  )
            String SPReceiveString( Number serialPortL, Number maxLength, NumberVariable actual )
            String SPReceiveHexString( Number serialPortL, Number maxLength, NumberVariable actual )
            void SPSetRTS( Number serialPortL, Boolean on )
            void SPSetDTR( Number serialPortL, Boolean on )
```

Any serial port opened by the commands must be closed by the script too, or it will remain open (and hence blocked).

Edit: Later versions of GMS call the DLL `SerialControlPlugin.dll`